# whereBetween doesnt pick up the data from database

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I am trying to get some date in between two different days:

```
$t = TrackingCode::where("organization_id", 10)
    ->whereBetween("tracking_codes.created_at", [Carbon::parse('2018-02-12 00:00:00'),
        Carbon::parse('2018-02-13 23:59:59')])->get()->toArray();
```

I have one row where created at its `2018-02-13 13:33:41` but its not working I get an empty array/collection back;

I've also tried this so far without any success:

```
where("created_at", ">",Carbon::parse('2018-02-12 00:00:00'))
->orWhere("created_at","<", Carbon::parse('2018-02-13 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to chain whereDate()->whereDate() to mimick the whereBetween functionality. You might also consider moving this logic to a query scope on the model.

```
$query
->whereDate("tracking_codes.created_at", ">", Carbon::parse('2018-02-12 00:00:00')
->whereDate("tracking_codes.created_at", "<", Carbon::parse('2018-02-13 23:59:59')
->get()->toArray();
```

But maybe you can try to convert the carbon instances to a datetimestring via Carbon::parse('2018-02-12 00:00:00')->toDateTimeString().

```
$t = TrackingCode::where("organization_id", 10)
    ->whereBetween("tracking_codes.created_at", [Carbon::parse('2018-02-12 00:00:00')->toDateTimeString(),
        Carbon::parse('2018-02-13 23:59:59')->toDateTimeString()])->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `created_at` instead of `tracking_codes.created_at`?

```
$t = TrackingCode::where("organization_id", 10)
->whereBetween("created_at", [Carbon::parse('2018-02-12 00:00:00'),
    Carbon::parse('2018-02-13 23:59:59')])->get()->toArray();
```

Your code should work, but I saw this difference. Perhaps can help you.

Comment: Have you tried it without using Carbon? Your dates are in correct format

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the main problem in **carbon** class that you use it's good with the front end or with showing the data, but when you talk to MySQL database you must be more **formal**, so you can use something like this:-

```
$firstDate = date('2018-02-12 00:00:00', time());
$lastDate = date('2018-04-05 00:00:00', time());
$t = TrackingCode::where("organization_id", 10)
->whereBetween("created_at", [$firstDate, $lastDate])->get();
```